# Why is there https://stackoverflow.com/ (home-page) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Why is there is a https://stackoverflow.com/ (home-page) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions?

The question is not **what** is the difference between both URLs, which anyone can see but **why**. That is, whenever I log into the site I have one single purpose, see if there is someone facing a difficult, in an area or subject which I can help.

Currently `/question` is the place to go for me. Instead, I think, `/question` should be the home page. and all other "top of the week"/"best of the month" should move aside.

Comment: You should have been **clearer** in your initial question.

Comment: @random, the `why` was there at the first place. besides, someone edited this question making it sounds like a dumb a*s question.

Answer (score 5):

The home page has a few different things on it such as badges recently awarded etc - and the most active questions for the week/month (instead of options to sort by time and votes).

I suspect the simple reason is:

- The site *isn't* just questions. It's also tags, badges, and users. It therefore makes sense to have a /questions URL stem when looking at a specific question, and also when just looking at questions.
- You obviously need to have *something* at the home page too.

Personally I very rarely look at the home page. It might make some sense for the home page and the questions page to be the same, but it's not really a problem IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The `/questions` page gives you more sorting options, plus a preview of question content.

Comment: Not more, just different - you get "votes" and "newest" instead of "week" and "month" :)

Comment: I would argue that "week" and "month" aren't sorting options. :)

Comment: I'd argue otherwise. From reference.com: "To separate from others" (AHD).  :)

Answer (score 1):

> That is, whenever I log into the site I have one single purpose, see if there is someone facing a difficult, in an area or subject which I can help.

Yeah, but not every body shares that same single scheme! Some cats gotta know what's *hip*, what's *hot*, what's *going on in the world* - and the home page makes that happen!